# How can I format code properly in a ChatGPT prompt?

Tags: chatgpt

I've tried the usual markdown syntax, for example:

````
```py
# Here's my Python code
import this
```
````

But it doesn't seem to work, it just displays it literally as if it was plain text. I wasn't able to find information as to whether markdown was the right syntax, or if there's another one, or if there simply isn't one. But when it replies with code, it does display it in a proper format (monospace font and everything), so that seems to indicate that there might be a way.

Of course this doesn't hinder its comprehension of code in any way, it's just for me, if I want to review the conversation later.

I have also looked through [ChatGPT's FAQ](https://help.openai.com/en/collections/3742473-chatgpt) (as suggested in the comments), especially through these three pages:

- https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6783457-chatgpt-general-faq
- https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6827250-chatgpt-emails-links-and-other-actions
- https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6825453-chatgpt-release-notes

But haven't found any additional information on how to format prompts.

---

There is a very recent discussion (dated February 21) exactly about this in the OpenAI Community -> [Add markdown support to input bar](https://community.openai.com/t/add-markdown-support-to-input-bar/70242).

*So far there is no working solution / workaround, and there is no fuller explanation either.*

Also there is a very recent discussion (dated February 13) exactly about this in the OpenAI Discord Server -> https://discord.com/channels/974519864045756446/1074756725695062096/1074764240063299584

*On this conversation it is mentioned the case of of LaTex for Match formulas. So far ther is no workink solution / workaround, and there is no fuller explanation either*.

Editor Note: I have tested using single backtick and triple backtick / code fences as the OP but they didn't work for me either.

Comment: Originally asked [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75484924/how-can-i-format-code-properly-in-a-chatgpt-prompt), but it might better belong here.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] It looks that ChatGPT always shows user input as plain text. Anyway, besides showing what you have tried, please search thoroughly the ChatGPT FAQ, the OpenAI Community and the OpenAI Discord Server. Edit your question to add what you found (i.e. the the resource, if any that explains how to use the ChatGPT user interface) and why it didn´meet your needs.

Comment: ChatGPT FAQ -> https://help.openai.com/en/collections/3742473-chatgpt, OpenAI Community -> https://community.openai.com/

Comment: Hello @Rubén, I've read your edit to my question. I think that this is actually part of the answer, why didn't you post it as a reply? Anyways, thank you for the information!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In first place b/c in my first comment I asked to search the sources mentioned in the content added, second because I'm encouraging that questions include references to the relevant content from the official resources for end-users of the respective web app.  Related [Let's make "research efforts" more specific: request to search the web app help](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4893/88163)

Comment: So, it seems that we can't do this with their current interface for now. But I'm glad we found some threads where other people are talking about this! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

We have learned from the current documentation and posts from OpenAI docs, community (forum) and Discord Server, that "vanilla" ChatGPT, the current version without any *hack*, third party tool, doesn't include a way for end-users to format input (prompts).

One thing that you might try is to us *web browser developers tools*  to edit the HTML/CSS for the node corresponding to an specificic *prompt*, i.e., to take a screenshot.

A more advanced option might be to use a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) (or userstyle). Some browsers allow the use of userscripts / userstyles without extensions, other require extensions.

A third option migth be the use of third party tools like web browser extensions which I don't feel confortable to use becuase, IMO, there are a lot of content that is missusing the term *ChatGPT*, some due to honest mistakes, some as a "marketing strategy" / [clickbait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait))  some doing [*social engineering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)) (trick users to give personal / sensitive information to later use it maliciously).

## Related

### About browser extensions

#### From Information Security Stack Exchange

- [Worst case scenario, what can a Chrome extension do with "Your data on all websites" and "Your tabs and browsing activity"?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/15259/151990)
- [How to defend myself against potential malicious browser add-ons?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/206349/151990)
- [Browser setups to stay safe from malware and unwanted stuff](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/221400/151990)
- [Are browser extensions inherently unsafe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/265245/151990)

Answer (score 2):

> it's just for me, if I want to review the conversation later.

My approach is to ask chatGPT directly to pretty print the code. Then I can see it easily.

[image: Screenshot of a chatgpt window where I ask the AI to pretty print the code.]

Comment: I just noticed that, as it usually does, it also modified your code a little: for instance, the function was renamed `updatescore` -> `updateScore`.

Answer (score 0):

Me: Can I show you my code in the same format that you present code? If so, how?

GPT: Yes, you can show me your code in the same format that I present code. To do so, you can use a code block.
To create a code block, you can enclose your code in triple backticks (''' `language  Code Here`''').
This will make it easier to read and understand your code. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!

Me: Like this?

(' ' ' cpp

#include

int main() {

std::cout << "Hello, World! The Moon says Hello!";

return 0;

}

' ' ' )

GPT: Yes! [image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please provide a brief context about the content of your answer / explain how this answer the question.

Comment: Yes but here your showing its answer, but when *you* entered the code it wasn't formatted properly. I know because I've asked it too. And when I tried what it told me to do, it never worked.

Comment: "Yes but here your showing its answer, but when you entered the code it wasn't formatted properly. I know because I've asked it too. And when I tried what it told me to do, it never worked."  Why did you put the answer in a comment and some AI generated garbage in the answer?

Comment: @BlindSpots I think this might be a rare exception to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful as a partial solution.

I am the author of
AImarkdown Script- MIT LICENSE

https://dev.to/aimarkdown/code-highlighter-responder-chatgpts-missing-feature-8dg

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Apps SE](/tour)! If you want to recommend your own product or website, there are some [guidelines in place](/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Please [edit] your post to explicitly state your affiliation. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)